# "The curvature of $\nabla=\mathrm d+\omega$ equals $\mathrm{d}\omega+\omega\wedge\omega$"

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

The following definition and lemma are from page $23$ of [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628).

**Definition**:

> Let $E$ be a vector bundle with base space $M$. The curvature $F$ of a covariant derivative $\nabla$ is defined by
> $$F(X,Y)=[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]-\nabla_{[X,Y]}$$
> for all vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $M$.

**Lemma**:

> If $E$ is a trivial bundle and $\nabla = \mathrm d + \omega$, then $F$ is given by the formula
> $$F=\mathrm{d}\omega+\omega\wedge\omega.$$

My problem is that I don't even know how $\mathrm d\omega$ and $\omega\wedge\omega$ are defined in this context. Since
$$(\mathrm d\alpha)(X,Y)=\mathrm{d}_X\iota_Y\alpha-\mathrm{d}_Y\iota_X\alpha-\iota_{[X,Y]}\alpha$$
and
$$(\alpha\wedge\alpha)(X,Y)=[\iota_X\alpha,\iota_Y\alpha]$$
for a $1$-form $\alpha$ (see e.g. equation $(1.3)$ and definition $1.6$ in the book), my guess would be that
$$(\mathrm d\omega)(X,Y)=\mathrm d_X\iota_Y\omega-\mathrm d_Y\iota_X\omega-\iota_{[X,Y]}\omega$$
and
$$(\omega\wedge\omega)(X,Y)=[\iota_X\omega,\iota_Y\omega].$$
Actually this seems to yield the correct result.$^1$ Nevertheless I would like to get a confirmation, preferably an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

---

$^1$ To simplify the notation, set $\omega_X:=\iota_X\omega$.
\begin{align}
&F(X,Y)\Phi=\nabla_X\nabla_Y\Phi-\nabla_Y\nabla_X\Phi-\nabla_{[X,Y]}\Phi&\\
&=\underbrace{(\mathrm{d}_X\mathrm{d}_Y-\mathrm{d}_Y\mathrm{d}_X)\Phi}_{=\mathrm{d}_{[X,Y]}\Phi}+\underbrace{\mathrm{d}_X(\omega_Y\Phi)-\omega_Y\mathrm{d}_X\Phi}_{=(\mathrm d_X\omega_Y)\Phi}+\underbrace{\omega_X\mathrm{d}_Y\Phi-\mathrm{d}_Y(\omega_X\Phi)}_{=-(\mathrm d_Y\omega_X)\Phi}&\\
&\phantom{={}}-\mathrm{d}_{[X,Y]}\Phi+[\omega_X,\omega_Y]\Phi-\omega_{[X,Y]}\Phi&\\
&=\underbrace{(\mathrm d_X\omega_Y-\mathrm d_Y\omega_X-\omega_{[X,Y]})}_{=(\mathrm{d}\omega)(X,Y)}\Phi+\underbrace{(\omega_X\omega_Y-\omega_Y\omega_X)}_{=(\omega\wedge\omega)(X,Y)}\Phi&\\
&=(\mathrm{d}\omega+\omega\wedge\omega)(X,Y)\Phi&
\end{align}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_form#Curvature_form_in_a_vector_bundle

Comment: I find the notation here unclear. If the trivial bundle is $E = M \times \mathbb{R}^k$, then each standard basis vector $e_j \in \mathbb{R}^k$ defines a section of $E$ and therefore, there is a a matrix of $1$-forms $\omega^i_j$ such that $$\nabla_X e_j = \langle\omega^i_j,X\rangle.$$  Denote that matrix by $\omega$. Therefore, given a section $s = s^je_j$, $$\nabla s = ds^j e_j + s^j \nabla e_j = ds^j e_j + s^j\omega_j^ie_i = (ds^j + s^i\omega^j_i)e_j = (d + \omega)s.$$

Comment: Thank you for making me feel better about always finding differential geometry notation confusing.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I admit that the notation in my question is terrible. IMO it was not that bad to use $\omega_X$ instead of $\iota_X\omega$ (which is simply an endomorphism valued function), so it makes sense to write $\mathrm d_X\omega_Y$, which is just another endomorphism-valued function.

Comment: @Filippo - Oh, I did not mean to single out you - sorry if it came across that way. Diff. geom. equations always seem to need more of "... and what we mean by this notation here is..." than other areas I've studied.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Most importantly, my calculation was wrong. I just fixed it. In addition, I chose a more compact notation for the proof. I hope it is more readable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your question about $d\omega$ and $\omega\wedge\omega$:

If the trivial bundle is $E = M \times \mathbb{R}^k$, then each standard basis vector $e_j \in \mathbb{R}^k$ defines a section of $E$ and therefore, there is a a matrix of $1$-forms $\omega^i_j$ such that $$\nabla_X e_j = \langle\omega^i_j,X\rangle e_i.$$  Denote that matrix by $\omega$. Therefore, given a section $s = s^je_j$, $$\nabla s = ds^j e_j + s^j \nabla e_j = ds^j e_j + s^j\omega_j^ie_i = (ds^j + s^i\omega^j_i)e_j = (d + \omega)s.$$ Then $d\omega$ is simply the matrix whose components are $d\omega^i_j$ and $\omega\wedge\omega$ is the matrix of 2-forms whose components are $\omega^i_p\wedge\omega^p_j$.

Here's another way to say the same thing: First, note that treating $E$ as a trivial bundle is essentially the same as choosing a frame of sections of $E$ and writing any section of $E$ with respect to the frame.

In particular, for each $X \in T_pM$, there is a matrix $A_X$ of coefficients such that
$$
\nabla_X s_j = s_i(A_X)_j^i.
$$
Since the map $X \rightarrow A_X$ is point wise linear, there exist $1$-forms $\omega^i_j$ such that
$$
\nabla s_j = s_i\omega_j^i.
$$
Given any section $s = a^js_j$,
$$
  \nabla s = \nabla(a^js_j) = da^js_j + a^j\omega^i_js_i = (da^j + a^i\omega_i^j)s_j
$$
In this sense,
$$
  \nabla = d + \omega.
$$

The curvature tensor at $p \in T_pM$ is defined as follows: Given $X, Y\in T_pM$ and a section $s$ of $E$, it is
$$
F(X,Y)s = \nabla_X(\nabla_Ys) - \nabla_Y(\nabla_Xs) - \nabla_{[X,Y]}s \in E_p.
$$
You can verify that $F(X,Y)s$ depends only on $s(p)$ and therefore for each $p \in M$ and $X, Y \in T_pM$, defines a bundle map
$$
F(X,Y): E_p \rightarrow E_p.
$$
In particular, for each $p \in M$ and $X, Y \in T_pM$, there exists a matrix $B_{X,Y}$ such that
$$
F(X,Y)s_j(p) = s_i(p)(B_{X,Y})^i_j.
$$
It can be verified that each $(B_{X,Y})^i_j$ defines a differential $2$-form $\Omega^i_j$ on $M$ such that
$$
(B_{X,Y})^i_j = \langle \Omega^i_j, X\otimes Y\rangle.
$$
Therefore,
$$
F(X,Y)s_j = s_i\langle\Omega^i_j,X\otimes Y\rangle.
$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
F(X,Y)s_j &= \nabla_X(\nabla_Ys_j) - \nabla_Y(\nabla_XSs_j) - \nabla_{[X,Y]}s_j\\
  &=\nabla_X(s_i\langle\omega^i_j,Y\rangle)
  -
  \nabla_Y(s_i\langle\omega^i_j,X\rangle)
    - s_i\langle \omega^i_j,[X,Y]\rangle\\
  &= (\nabla_Xs_i)\langle\omega^i_j,Y\rangle + s_i(X\langle\omega^i_j,Y\rangle)
  - (\nabla_Ys_i)\langle\omega^i_j,X\rangle - s_i(Y\langle\omega^i_j,X\rangle) - s_i\langle\omega^i_j,[X,Y]\rangle\\
&= s_i(\langle \omega^i_k,X\rangle\langle\omega^k_j,Y\rangle + X\langle\omega^i_j,Y\rangle
  - \langle \omega^i_k,Y\rangle\langle\omega^k_j,X\rangle - Y\langle\omega^i_j,X\rangle - \langle \omega^i_j,[X,Y]\rangle)\\
          &= s_i(X\langle\omega^i_j,Y\rangle - Y\langle \omega^i_j,X\rangle - \langle \omega^i_j,[X,Y]\rangle + \langle\omega_k^i,X\rangle\langle\omega^k_j,Y\rangle - \langle \omega_k^i,Y\rangle\langle\omega^k_j,X\rangle\\
  &= S_i(d\omega^i_j + \omega^i_k\wedge\omega^k_j).
\end{align*}
From all this, follows that
$$
F(X,Y)s_j = s_i(d\omega^i_j + \omega^i_k\wedge\omega^k_j),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\Omega^i_j = d\omega^i_j + \omega^i_k\wedge\omega^k_j
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a doubt though: In my question, $\omega$ is defined by $\nabla=\mathrm d+\omega$, whereas in your answer $\omega\equiv\nabla$
 (i.e. your $\omega$ is the representation of $\nabla$ w.r.t. to the frame). So I think that the equation
$$F=\mathrm d\omega+\omega\wedge \omega$$
has a different meaning.

Comment: To put it bluntly, to me it looks like you have proven$$F=\mathrm d\nabla+\nabla\wedge\nabla.$$

Comment: Here's one way to explain the situation: Given a section $s = Sa$ and $X \in T_pM$, \begin{align*}  \nabla_Xs &= \nabla_X(Sa) \\ &=  (\nabla_XS)a + S\langle X,da\rangle\\ &= S\langle \omega,X\rangle a + S\langle X,da\rangle\\ &= S\langle da + \omega, X\rangle.\end{align*} Therefore, $\nabla s = S(d + \omega)a.$

Comment: Yes, I see that my answer isn't quite right. I'll fix it when I get a chance.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing your answer! It helped me to find the mistake in my calculation. Now my calculation is consistent with your calculation.